# Freemarker - Split String based on New Line

Tags: netsuite, freemarker, suitescript

I want to split a string based on the lines, meaning seperating contents on seperate lines.

```
Example -

Hello I
am
Bill Gates

Final Array should be ["Hello I","am","Bill Gates"]
```

I tried using split function and passing '\n' but it ain't working.

```
<#assign finalValue = body?split('\n') />
```

I am not getting the desired result in this case. Can you please help me out with this?

**For more details, read below -**

I am trying to fetch country from an address. Country is always on the last line of address, so I am trying to SPLIT the address based on lines, thus fetching last line which is the desired output.

```
Example -
ABC, Industries Ltd.,
XYZ Street,
United States.
```

So here, I am using split function as address?split("\n") but it ain't working.

So, I tried splitting using Developers Console and it worked fine there. Used split() function.

Upon fetching the address value though, I am getting it as -

`ABC, Industries Ltd., \n XYZ Street, \nUnited States`.

Hence, thought of splitting using \n but it ain't working!

Comment: Have you tried "\r" (Carriage Return), "\r\n" (Carriage Return & Line Feed), "<br>" (HTML line break element), "char(10)" (SQL Line Feed), or "char(13)" (SQL Carriage Return) instead of "\n" (line feed).  I don't explicitly know which works where in NetSuite, but they are just different options of making a space/line break

Comment: When I am trying to fetch the value I wanna split using console, this is the format in which I am getting the string - "Hello I \n am \nBill Gates". So basically I have this string and need to split this based on '\n'. I tried using '\r' and '\r\n' but none of them worked.

Comment: Can you show the actual template you are using, and what result do you  get?

Comment: @ddekany I have added details to the question. Please go through it.

Comment: @Jerry2109 You are still not showing the template that generates that output, only an assignment. Also I'm not sure why in the output you show literal `\n`-s instead of actual line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

The usual problem is that there are 3 kind of line-breaks in use: `\r\n` (Windows and some Web protocols), `\n` (everything else), and very rarely `\r` (old Mac). The split that works with all is `?split(r'\R', 'r')`. Note that the `R` is capital in `\R`. That's a regular expression construct, supported since Java 8.

Comment: When I am trying to fetch the value I wanna split using console, this is the format in which I am getting the string - "Hello I \n am \nBill Gates". So basically I have this string and need to split this based on '\n'. I tried using '\r' and '\r\n' and also [r'\R', 'r'] but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Likely doesn't help the OP, but might help someone else from the frustration of trying to split on line break for an advanced PDF in NetSuite using Freemarker!

You need to use <br />

> ${var?split(r"<br />", "r")}